# Jquery/Js: Hide/Show Divs based on select box option values

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are Dynamic dependent select controls. The sets of values of (1-3, 4-6, 7-9) determine the use hide/show divs function.  The problem is the function i have only hide/show depending on the div id. How can i make the function hide/show div depended on the values(1-3, 4-6, 7-9) found in the selectbox?

**Jquery**

```
$('#select').change(function() {
   $('#sub1, #sub2, #sub3').hide();
   $('#sub' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')).show();
});
```

**Html Setup**

```
<html>
<select size="6" id="category">
     <option value="">categories 1-3 </option>
     <option value="">----</option>
     <option value="">----</option>
</select>

<div id="sub1" style="display:none">
<select name="subc1" size="6">
     <option value="1">subcategories 4-6</option>
     <option value="2">---</option>
     <option value="3">---</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="sub2" style="display:none">
<select name="subc2" size="6">
      <option value="4">subcategories 7-9</option>
      <option value="5">----</option>
      <option value="6">----</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="sub3" style="display:none">
<select name="subc3" size="6">
      <option value="7">End</option>
      <option value="8">----</option>
      <option value="9">----</option>
</select>   
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: You would be much better off adding a class to the div elements instead of using the ID attribute in the selectors.

Comment: where is the DOM element with id as **select**

Comment: @jonhecoder2346: mark 1 answer as accepted if issue resolved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee to change minor change in your category `select`

```
<select size="6" id="category">
     <option value="1">categories 1-3 </option>
     <option value="2">----</option>
     <option value="3">----</option>
</select>


$('select#category').on('change', function() {
  $('div[id=^sub]:visible').hide();
  $('div#sub' + this.value).show();
});
```

can also use `.change()` instead of `.on('change')`.

```
 $('select#category').change(function() {
  $('div[id=^sub]:visible').hide();
  $('div#sub' + this.value).show();
});
```

**NOTE:**

`$('div[id=^sub]:visible')` will point to all `div`s that have `id` start with `sub` and `visible`.

You are trying with `$('#select')` which need to be `$('#category')` or `$('select#category')`.

**According to your comment:**

Complete solution will look like following:

```
function isOnlyDashed(text) {
    return text.replace(/-/g, '').length === 0;
}

$('select#category').change(function() {
    var text = $('option:selected', this).text();
    if (!isOnlyDashed(text)) {
        $('div[id=^sub]:visible').hide();
        $('div#sub' + this.value).show();
    }
});


$('select[name^=subc]').change(function() {
    var text = $('option:selected', this).text();
    if (!isOnlyDashed(text)) {
        $(this).parent() // jump to parent div
        .next('div[id^=sub]:hidden') // go to next hidden div
        .show();
    }
});
```

**[Complete Workout](http://jsfiddle.net/5CU5p/1/)**

Comment: Thank you, with your help I am getting closer to my goal . The only thing is the select boxes are dependable. Instead of the first select box show/hide all the other select boxes, First select box will take to you to the next select box, then the next select box will take you last select box. SO there might be the possibility of displaying all select boxes at once.  Here is a jsfiddle of your work: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FwBb2/7/)

Comment: excellent!  Although a minor issue is still showing up: In the main select box when clicking (----) option it still displays select box 3 and 4. I only want main select box to display select box 2. everything else works fine :)

Comment: @jonthecoder2346 check update according to your second comment

Comment: perfect!! You have solved me an issue that i have been trying to overcome for days. Thank you your perseverance in helping me. Your answer is truly the best and most valid.

Answer (score 1):

select the value from drop down change function and do the operation depends on the value of drop down, following is the sample code

```
$(function() // Shorthand for $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').change(function() {
            if($(this).val() == 1)
            {
              $('#sub1').hide();
              $('#sub2').show();
            }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have an incorrect selector.

```
$('#select')...
```

should be

```
$('select')...
```

Also, this part is wrong

```
  $('#sub' + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')).show();
```

Replace it with this

```
  $('#sub' + $(this).val()).show();
```

Finally, having different elements with the same name/id "sub1" is probably a bad idea, though technically not illegal. It is certainly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FwBb2/1/

I have made minor changes in your Jquery code as well as added value in your first select drop-down list which was missing rest hope this helps.

Please lemme know if I missed anything! B-)

**code**

```
$('select').change(function() {
   $('#sub1, #sub2, #sub3').hide();

   $('#sub' + $(this).val()).show();
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<select id="category">
     <option value="1">categories 1-3 </option>
     <option value="2">----</option>
     <option value="3">----</option>
</select>

<div id="sub1" style="display:none">
<select name="subc1" size="6">
     <option value="1">subcategories 4-6</option>
     <option value="2">---</option>
     <option value="3">---</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="sub2" style="display:none">
<select name="subc2" size="6">
      <option value="4">subcategories 7-9</option>
      <option value="5">----</option>
      <option value="6">----</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="sub3" style="display:none">
<select name="subc3" size="6">
      <option value="7">End</option>
      <option value="8">----</option>
      <option value="9">----</option>
</select>   
</div>
</html>​
```